# ASP.NET to PHP array conversion

Tags: php, asp.net, arrays

I have an array in asp. Example SampleArray(100,100). This in PHP would be SampleArray[100][100] if I am correct. I am trying to populate this array and this is what I have so far:

```
$sampleArray = array(array());
$counter1 = 0;
$counter2 = 0;
for($counter1; $counter1 < 100; $counter1++)
{
    for($counter2; $counter2 < 100; $counter2++)
    {
        $sampleArray[$counter1][$counter2] = $counter1 . " , " . $counter2;
    }
    $counter2 = 0;
}
echo("Sample Array size: " . count($sampleArray));
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Well am correct in assuming this means the the array would have 100 x 100 values? Because the echo only gives me a size of 100

Comment: Correct. You have an array of 100 elements. Each of those elements is an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not using your for loops in an efficient way. The first element of the for loop is for initializing the counter.

```
$sampleArray = array();
for($counter1=0; $counter1<100; ++$counter1) {
  $sampleArray[$counter1] = array();
  for($counter2=0; $counter2<100; ++$counter2)
    $sampleArray[$counter1][$counter2] = $counter1.','.$counter2;
}
```

Now, you will have a 100x100 array.

The MAIN difference is that I declared each element of $sampleArray to be an array instead of using array(array()) which makes one element in the top level that contains an array instead of 100 elements that each contain an array.